# AxMSTSCLib how to redirect camera from client to remote session?

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

I am using `AxMSTSCLib` to develop a Windows application for establishing RDP connections. But I don't know how to redirect a physical camera from client to remote RDP session.

I tried to add `camerastoredirect:s:*` and `devicestoredirect:s:*` in .rdp file to redirect camera, it worked, I can use the camera in remote desktop via RDP.

But I can't find the correct property in `AxMSTSCLib` library to enable this feature.

I've tried to redirect all possible/dynamic devices, but it didn't work at all. Here is the code:

```cs
public AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting oRemote;
oRemote = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting();

oRemote.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectDevices = true;
oRemote.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectPorts = true;
oRemote.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectPOSDevices = true;

MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5 ocx = (MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5)oRemote.GetOcx();
ocx.RedirectDynamicDevices = true;
for (int i = 0; i < ocx.DeviceCollection.DeviceCount; i++)
{
    MSTSCLib.IMsRdpDevice device = ocx.DeviceCollection.get_DeviceByIndex((uint)i);
    device.RedirectionState = true;
}
```

I found [IMsRdpCameraRedirConfigCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpcameraredirconfigcollection-addconfig) in newer API documents, need to upgrade `IMsRdpClientNonScriptable` from 5 to 7.

I tried to print its count before setting `Redirected` as true, like this:

```cs
MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable7 ocx = (MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable7)oRemote.GetOcx();
Logger.Log("[ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.Count]:" + (ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.Count).ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.Count; i++)
{
    MSTSCLib.IMsRdpCameraRedirConfig camera = ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.get_ByIndex((uint)i);
    Logger.Log("[camera.FriendlyName]:" + camera.FriendlyName);
    camera.Redirected = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, I got zero.

According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpcameraredirconfigcollection-addconfig), it looks like I have to add the camera symbolic link to the collection using `AddConfig` method. I stuck at this point, how do I add a camera symbolic link to the `IMsRdpCameraRedirConfigCollection`? How to get camera symbolic link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `IMsRdpCameraRedirConfigCollection` is empty in the beginning? Since you didn't [Rescan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpcameraredirconfigcollection-rescan) connected camera devices.

```cs
MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable7 ocx = (MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable7)oRemote.GetOcx();
// enumerates connected camera devices
ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.Rescan();
for (int i = 0; i < ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.Count; i++)
{
    MSTSCLib.IMsRdpCameraRedirConfig camera = ocx.CameraRedirConfigCollection.get_ByIndex((uint)i);
    camera.Redirected = true;
}
```

That's it, all connected camera devices will be redirected to the remote desktop.